# How can I add the custom taxonomy categories to the posts and pages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to build new wordpress plugin.
Additional to the default wordpress categories box in the publishing screen of posts and pages, I want to add another box for custom taxonomy categories , How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need to do is just pass required post types as array in the second parameter for [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/register_taxonomy) function call:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_init' );
function wpse8170_init() {
    register_taxonomy( 'my-taxonomy', array( 'post' ), array(
        ...
    ) );

    // or call this function if your taxonomy is already registered
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'my-taxonomy', 'page' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, what if the taxonomies are registered  in another plugin ?

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer I have updated my snippet.